# sed: replace part of line in text file at recognized character with entire line from another file

Tags: bash, sed

I have many sets of corresponding .txt files. I want to recognize a specific character `":"` in the first .txt file (text1.txt) and then replace it (and the remainder of the line in text1.txt) with the corresponding line from the other .txt file (text2.txt). I would also like to add an additional character say `"*"` before the copied value.

text1.txt looks something like this:

```
*
10.04:60.429 
*
*
*
12.023:60.078
*
9.033:60.045 
*
9.023:60.062 
*
*
```

and text2.txt looks something like this:

```
* 
11
* 
* 
* 
4
* 
10
* 
9
* 
*
```

The output should look like this:

```
*
10.04*11
*
*
*
12.023*4
*
9.033*10 
*
9.023*9
*
*
```

any ideas on the best way to do this with sed?

Comment: sed -i and sed -e but I couldn't dynamically find the value from the second text file and replace part of the line without knowing the value I wanted to replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below `awk` script should do

```
awk 'BEGIN{i=1;j=1}
     NR==FNR{text1[i++]=$0;next}
     /:/{gsub(/:[^:]*/,"*" text1[j],$0)}
     #Note :[^:] looks for the last occurence of : in text1 strings
     {j++}1' text2.txt text1.txt
```

**Result**

```
*
10.04*11
*
*
*
12.023*4
*
9.033*10
*
9.023*9
*
*
```

Comment: is there a reason to use awk instead of sed here?

Comment: @Kosagl well yes, you need to remember something from one file and use it in the other. Would be tedious with sed